# PHP Multiple File Upload show each file name

Tags: php

Hello I prepare to create a Web apps to make user uploads the Multiple File.

Here is my html code.

```
<input type="file" name="filesname[]"  multiple/>
```

but I want to show the file name in page, and upload the filename to database.
such as user will upload the "A.jpg", "B.png" and "C.txt";

I use this php code is work. It is working about show the multiple file.

```
foreach($_FILES['filesname']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name =  $key.$_FILES['filesname']['name'][$key];
    echo "$file_name".",";}
```

when upload success the html page show

```
result A.jpg,B.png,C.txt,
```

but I want to upload the file name in database.

show I used this code

```
$sql="INSERT into file_name_table (filename) VALUES('$file_name'.','); ";
```

but it just update the first file_name in database.

```
A.jpg,
```

any idea ?? thanks

Comment: you need to use "filename .=" to append to the file name

Comment: Also don't forget to declare the variable first before appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your query inside the for each loop

EX.

```
foreach($_FILES['filesname']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
$file_name =  $key.$_FILES['filesname']['name'][$key];
$sql="INSERT into file_name_table (filename) VALUES('$file_name'.',');";$sql->execute();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want (note the .= instead of =) and then echo outside the loop

```
foreach($_FILES['filesname']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
{
    $file_name .=  $_FILES['filesname']['name'][$key] . ",";
}
echo "$file_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be storing file names in an array and then convert them to string with implode. It would be like

```
<?php
        $_user = 'root';
        $_password= 'root';
        $_db = 'localtest';
        $_host = 'localhost';
        $_port = 3306;
$con = new mysqli($_host, $_user, $_password, $_db);
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
$file_name = array();
foreach($_FILES['filesname']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    array_push($file_name, $key.$_FILES['filesname']['name'][$key]);
}
$files_name = implode(', ', $file_name);
echo $files_name;
$sql="INSERT into file_name_table (filename) VALUES('$files_name'); ";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Tested above code and it will output. The database will be updated with the same string.

```
0001.pdf, 1201.pdf, 2747_8.pdf
```

Note: queries like above is not recommended as they are vulnerable to sql injection. Recommended to use prepare statements with place holders instead like bellow

```
<?php
        $_user = 'root';
        $_password= 'root';
        $_db = 'localtest';
        $_host = 'localhost';
        $_port = 3306;
$con = new mysqli($_host, $_user, $_password, $_db);
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
$file_name = array();
foreach($_FILES['filesname']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    array_push($file_name, $key.$_FILES['filesname']['name'][$key]);
}
$files_name = implode(', ', $file_name);
echo $files_name;
$sql="INSERT into file_name_table (filename) VALUES(?); ";
$stmt = $con-> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $files_name);
$stmt -> execute();
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```